# Range []string returns uint8

Tags: arrays, string, go, yaml

I have a yaml file that is currently written as:

```
resource:
      File:
        containment_path:
        - File
        - File::Value
      Default:
        containment_path:
        - Default
        - Default::Echo
        - Default[main]
      Exec:
        containment_path:
        - Stage
        - Exec::File
        - Exec[File]
```

I use structure to get containment_path:

```
type Yaml struct {
    ContainmentPath      []string      `yaml:"containment_path"`
}
```

And i want to range over ContainmentPath to get the second value in containment_path : File::Value, Default::Echo, Exec::File

I do this code :

```
for _, v := range m.ContainmentPath {
    spew.Dump("Value ContainmentPath:", m.ContainmentPath)
    spew.Dump("Value v[1]:", v[1])      
    value = v[1]
}
```

When I run it I get this for ContainmentPath:

```
(string) (len=8) "Value ContainmentPath:"
([]string) (len=2 cap=2) {
 (string) (len=4) "File",
 (string) (len=11) "File::Value"
}
(string) (len=8) "Value ContainmentPath:"
([]string) (len=3 cap=3) {
 (string) (len=7) "Default",
 (string) (len=13) "Default::Echo",
 (string) (len=13) "Default[main]"
}
(string) (len=8) "Value ContainmentPath:"
([]string) (len=3 cap=3) {
 (string) (len=5) "Stage",
 (string) (len=10) "Exec::File",
 (string) (len=10) "Exec[File]"
}
```

When I run it I get this for v[1]:

```
(string) (len=11) "Value v[1]:"
(uint8) 114
(string) (len=11) "Value v[1]:"
(uint8) 105
(string) (len=11) "Value v[1]:"
(uint8) 116
```

And I want to get for v[1] the values : File::Value, Default::Echo, Exec::File 
How I can do this in Go ? 
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you leave `spew.Dump` alone and print your `v[1]` using `fmt.Println`? I mean, you have a non-problem produced by the way you attempt to debug your problem. `spew` is a great package but it requires certain knowledge to be used properly.

Comment: @kostix when i use fmt.Println i get Value v[1] 114 Value v[1] 105 Value v[1] 116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are indexing into a `string`, not a `[]string`.**

`ContainmentPath` is a slice of strings.

When you run `for _, v := range m.ContainmentPath`, `v` is taking on the value of each string in the slice. So `v` is of type `string`.

When you print `v[1]`, you are indexing into the string (without checking its length first, very bad idea) and printing the second character in the string which is a byte. A byte is just an alias for uint8.

Comment: Ah okay, so I have to index on my ContainmentPath variable directly

Comment: Just `m.ContainmentPath[1]`.